# mysql запрос на выбор самых часто повторяющихся

Tags: php, mysql

здравствуйте, есть поле tags (varchar) в таблице news (которое иногда пусто), как можно запросом выбрать из бд выбрать топ 5 самых часто повторяющихся тэгов из этого поля? тоесть типа самые популярные

Comment: поле 'tags' ... что то мне буква 's' в конце не нравится, у вас там что ли несколько тегов в одном поле ? теги должны быть в отдельной таблице, по одному в записи  id-новости, тег (или id-тега)

Comment: @Mike Или через кросс-таблицу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в поле `tags` у Вас содержится по одному тегу, тогда Вам нужно выбрать записи с непустым полем `tags` (`WHERE tags IS NOT NULL`), с группировкой по полю `tags` (`GROUP BY tags`), подсчитать количество записей в каждой группе (`COUNT(*)`), отсортировать группы в порядке убывания количества (`ORDER BY cnt DESC`) и взять первые пять групп (`LIMIT 5`)

```
SELECT
  `tags`,
  COUNT(*) AS `cnt`
FROM
  `news`
WHERE
  `tags` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  `tags`
ORDER BY
  `cnt` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Если же в нем содержится несколько тегов, то тогда Вам нужно пересмотреть структуру Вашей БД

1. Создать отдельную таблицу `tags` с полями `id`, `name`
2. Создать кросс-таблицу `news_tags` с полями `new_id`, `tag_id`
3. Убрать из таблицы `news` поле `tags`

Тогда Ваша Задача будет решаться таким запросом

```
SELECT
  t.`name`
  COUNT(*) AS `cnt`
FROM
  `news_tags` nt
  LEFT JOIN `tags` t ON (nt.`tag_id` = t`id`)
GROUP BY
  nt.`tag_id`,
  t`name`
ORDER BY
  `cnt` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

P.S. Если тег для новости все-таки один, то все равно лучше завести отдельную таблицу `tags`, а поле `news.tags` переименовать в `news.tag_id` и сделать ссылкой на таблицу `tags`

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ объяснением решения.

Comment: спасибо, подскажите как сделать чтобы при выборе (в первом примере) не выбирало ещё там где поле путо, а то получается на первом месте идет пустота

Comment: @turik97 `WHERE tags IS NOT NULL`